# How can I re-use css properties across css modules in nested selectors?

Tags: css-modules

Some background: I've converted my designer's Sketch text styles to classes in a css module. For this example, I have a "labels.module.css" file, containing the styles for each type of label in a class name. Here is an excerpt (the `@apply` comes from tailwind):

```css
.labelNormalLight,
.labelNormalMidGray,
.labelNormal,
.labelNormalWhite
{
    @apply font-normal font-sans text-xs leading-3;
}

.labelNormalLight {
    @apply text-neutralMediumLight;
}
```

Now I have an element that I'm using the style `.labelNormal` on. However, when that element's parent is hovered over, I need to switch the styles to that of `.labelNormalLight`. For this, I wrote another `.module.css` file, and attempted to compose the two styles inside it:

```css
.name {
    composes: labelNormal from '../styles/labels.module.css';
}

.person:hover .name {
    composes: labelNormalLight from '../styles/labels.module.css';
}
```

This however fails, as CSS Modules do not allow composing except within single local class names, per this error:

```
Error: composition is only allowed when selector is single :local class name not in ":local(.person):hover :local(.name)"
```

So my question is: How do I achieve keeping my CSS DRY, but also allow me to override styles based on parent states? I've thought about exporting the values, but then I have to know what values to override.

**Update:**
So I was able to accomplish this using using Sass's `@extend`, by specifying `%labelNormalLight` and extending that. I wasn't able to achieve this with tailwind however, due to me being unable to get tailwind working in Sass. I'd still like to know how to do this without sass though, as it's literally the only reason I'd need it.

Comment: I might be completely wrong here but can't we achieve these using CSS variables?
https://codeburst.io/magic-of-css-sass-variables-b07ae8c1b775

Comment: @VinuPrasad Unfortunately not, since I can't group properties into one variable. The point is I need to share multiple properties at once. I don't want to have to know what properties I need to set to achieve a style.

Comment: Oh ok got it, Does SASS mixins help u here ? something like this
https://codepen.io/vinu_pen/pen/wvgwzxP